# Why tkinter is calculating mouse event outside tkinter window?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am just trying to get mouse event(like mouse X position and mouse Y position) but tkinter is calculating mouse event outside the tkinter window.

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry('400x400')

def get_pos(event):
    print(f'x={event.x} y={event.y}')

window.bind('<Motion>',get_pos) #binding motion event with window

window.mainloop()
```

**Now if you run above code tkinter will prompt window of "400x400" dimensional , now acc to code if
you hover or move mouse pointer on any direction in tkinter window it should print mouse position. But if you move mouse pointer outside of tkinter window it still print mouse position.Why does it happening.

Why tkinter is printing mouse position even though mouse pointer is outside of tkinter window**

*I want to get(print) mouse position only if mouse is inside tkinter window , not outside of tkinter window.*

Thanks all of you for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why tkinter is printing mouse position even though mouse pointer is outside of tkinter window**

It is because the window is active. It is designed to work this way.

> I want to get(print) mouse position only if mouse is inside tkinter window , not outside of tkinter window.

You can easily filter out events that are outside the window by asking tkinter which widget is under the mouse. If tkinter returns `None`, the mouse is outside of the window.

```
def get_pos(event):
    if event.widget.winfo_containing(event.x, event.y) is not None:
        print(f'x={event.x} y={event.y}')
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
WIDTH = 400; HEIGHT = 400
window.geometry(f'{WIDTH}x{HEIGHT}')  

def get_pos(event):
    if (event.x > WIDTH) or (event.y > HEIGHT): return
    print(f'x={event.x} y={event.y}')
```

etc.

This should eliminate the printing within window bounds, however as for the question:

Why is tkinter doing this?

I don't know as I don't know the code behind tkinter, but I can only assume that it gets its mouse position data from your OS which I also assume doesn't have knowledge of your window bounds. Just a guess but it's all I've got. Shouldn't be a problem anyway, just use the if statement at the start of necessary functions.

EDIT: I've noticed Bryan Oakley's answer is probably better, so I would use their's.
(See my comment on this answer to read what I mean)

Comment: I would only use my solution if Bryan Oakley's solution doesn't work, as they are clearly more knowledgable about the library and have provided a specific solution, my one note is that for more concise logic, the if statement on their's should be flipped and the content be replaced by a return statement, then outside of the if statement,  any other code you want in the function.

Comment: This will only work if the user doesn’t resize the window.

Comment: Appreciated the help , as @Bryan Oakley already acknowledge that if user resize window it wont work so going with solution of BryanOakely

Comment: oh ok sorry not much experience with tkinter sorry